# Restricting a github code search to repos fulfilling certain criteria

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to combine code and repository search on github? Preferably on the website, but if nothing else works, with the API?

I mulled over the search documentation on the github website but I can't find a mention of this.

I can find for repos that are starred by a certain number of people, in a certain language and have them sorted by the star count.
stars:">100" language:Java

I can find code that uses certain keywords.
writeObject extension:java

But I can't seem to find code with certain keywords, but have the search restricted to projects with a certain number of stars and I can't have the code results sorted by stars either.

How can I combine the two?

Looking for projects that use the Java serialization API with compatiblity code for older versions that aren't some student's hobby project.